# Where are the class files of jsp files stored in netbeans 12.0

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I have two files in my sample web application: '**index.jsp, page1.jsp**'. When i run this web application where are the class files of these two jsp files stored in **netbeans 12.0**?

It shows in netbeans itself but when I **searched** for the **class files** in *project folder* , i couldn't find any.

Comment: What kind of NetBeans project? Maven?  Ant?  Gradle?

Comment: it's ANT project..